# On the definition of uniformly pointwise bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, soft-question, definition

Royden Page 78:

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly pointwise bounded on E, that is, there is a number $M>0$ for which $|f_n|<M$ on $E$ for all $n$.

To me, this looks like the definition of uniformly bounded. There doesn't seem to be anything "pointwise" about this definition.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The "pointwise" does not make any sense at all.

Comment: So is there a definition for nonuniform boundedness?